# Pandas save counts of multiple columns in single dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns now which appears like this

```
Model          IsJapanese   IsGerman   
BenzC             0            1
BensGla           0            1
HondaAccord       1            0
HondaOdyssey      1            0
ToyotaCamry       1            0
```

I want to create a new dataframe and have TotalJapanese and TotalGerman as two columns in the same dataframe.

I am able to achieve this by creating 2 different dataframes. But wondering how to get both the counts in a single dataframe.

please suggest thank you!

Editing and adding another similar dataframe to this [sorry notsure whether its allowed-but trying

Second dataset- am trying to save multiple counts in single dataframe, based on repetition of data.

Here is my sample dataset

```
Store        Address           IsLA             IsGA
Albertsons   Cross St           1                 0
Safeway      LeoSt              0                 1
Albertsons   Main St            0                 1
RiteAid      Culver St          1                 0
```

My aim is to prepare a new dataset with multiple counts per store
The result should be like this

```
Store      TotalStores TotalLA TotalGA 
Alberstons 2           1        1 
Safeway    1           0        1 
RiteAid    1           1        0
```

Is it possible to achieve these in single dataframe ?

Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby('Store').sum().assign(Total=lambda df: df.sum(axis='columns'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to store the sum of Japanese cars and German cars, and manually create a dataframe using them:

```
j , g =sum(df['IsJapanese']),sum(df['IsGerman']) 

total_df = pd.DataFrame({'TotalJapanese':j,
                         'TotalGerman':g},index=['Totals'])
```

---

```
print(total_df)
 
        TotalJapanese  TotalGerman
Totals              3            2
```

Another way would be to transpose (`T`) your dataframe, `sum(axis=1)`, and tranpose back:

```
>>> total_df_v2 = pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('Model').T.sum(axis=1)).T

print(total_df_v2)

   IsJapanese  IsGerman
           3         2
```

To answer your 2nd question, you can use a [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) on your 'Store' column, use parameter `count` on Address and `sum` on your other two columns. Then you can `rename()` your columns if needed:

```
resulting_df  = df.groupby('Store').agg({'Address':'count',
                         'IsLA':'sum',
                         'IsGA':'sum'}).\
    rename({'Address':'TotalStores',
             'IsLA':'TotalLA',
             'IsGA':'TotalGA'},axis=1)
```

Prints:

```
            TotalStores  IsLA  IsGA
Store                              
Albertsons            2     1     1
RiteAid               1     1     0
Safeway               1     0     1
```

Comment: Thanks much for the suggestions! let me try these.

Comment: I have a similar question for another counts - would i ask it here -or should i ask as another ?

Comment: Hi, I will get you the answer for the 2nd question too, but it's not good practise to do that. You have accepted and then un-accepted the answer because you added an extra question, which is not very an approached used in SO.

Comment: Is ```Alebrstones``` supposed to be written differently in the rows or is it a typo?

Comment: so sorry - i only did that thinking the question maynot come up to answer.

Comment: That's okay, just keep it in mind for the future. Let me know if my answer to your second question works, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230733/discussion-between-sophocles-and-mmenon).

Comment: Thanks very much! yes seeing the result. Quick question - How do i save these to a dataframe so i can export ?